# TypeError: _models_Products__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am making  Next Js web application and browesr is showing type error in 7th line in first block of code .The error is under Product.find()
TypeError: *models_Products__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.default.find is not a function

```
   6 | const handler = async (req, res) => {
>  7 |   let products = await Product.find();
     |                       ^
   8 |  
   9 |   res.status(200).json({ products });
  10 | };
```

**This is my database of mongodb **

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connectDb = (handler) => async (req, res) => {
  if (mongoose.connections[0].readyState) {
    return handler(req, res);
  }
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
  return handler(req, res);
};
export default connectDb;

`
```

**This is connection of my database to next js app in api folder**

```
import connectDb from "../../database";
import Product from "../../models/Products";

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  let products = await Product.find();

  res.status(200).json({ products });
};

export default connectDb(handler);
```

**This  is my product schema*

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose")

const productSchema=new mongoose.Schema({

    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    slug:{
        type:String, required:true
    },
    desc:{type:String,required:true},
    img:{type:String,reuired:true},
    category:{type:String,reuired:true},
    size:{type:String},
    color:{type:String},
    price:{type:Number},
    availableQty:{type:String,required:true}
   

},{timestamps:true});

mongoose.models={}

export default mongoose.model=('Product',productSchema)
```

Comment: it worked bro ,You are brilliant .Thnaks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Try to export your `model` like this:

```
export default mongoose.models?.Product || mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

You may remove the `mongoose.models = {}` line.

Comment: Bro check the problem in stack overflow and if you can solve it https://stackoverflow.com/q/73540744/18259724

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me "mongoose": "^6.7.0" with nextjs->
use this as reference**

```
import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new Schema({
displayName: { type: String, required: true },
email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
phone: { type: String, unique: true },
password: { type: String },
pro: { type: Boolean, default: false },
author: { type: Boolean, default: false },
photoURL: { type: String },});
console.log(model); // undefined
console.log(models.UserModel); //this solved


const User = models.UserModel;

export default User;
```